# LDR is loading the word in a weird order after program working fine first few loops through. Bytes are flipped around. ARM7 Big Endian

Tags: assembly, endianness, arm7

Im working on an assignment for school. Im supossed to remove any instance of "the" in STRING1 and store it in STRING2. I wrote this program but its doing something weird after I loop through it a few times, when I detect 74 or 't' I check if the next 4 bytes are equal to "the" with a space or NULL and if it isnt equal I store it in memory. The program suddenly stops getting the right 4 bytes but works correctly in the beginning. Ive attatched a picture of when it stops working and my code.

Thanks in advance for the help. I that at the end I have to add something for the null space and make sure it stops right. Also Im very new to assembly so any advice is appreciated.

```
            AREA Assign5, CODE, READONLY
            ENTRY
            MOV r6,#0
            ADR r2, STRING1
            ADR r3, STRING2
            LDR r4, THE
            LDR r5, THEE
                    
        ;try checking if its equal and if its not then subtract from location and go back into storing the byte
        ;adress must be div 4 so acessing once is leading to problem
        
            LDRB r1,[r2],#1
            ;LDRB r4,[r5],#1
Loop        CMP r1,#0
            BEQ Stop
            CMP r1,#32
            BEQ EQ20
            CMP r1,#116
            BEQ EQ74
Store       STRB r1,[r3],#1
Next        LDRB r1,[r2],#1
            B Loop
        
EQ20        STRB r1,[r3],#1
            ;SUB r0,#4
            LDR r1,[r2],#4
            CMP r1,r4
            BEQ Next
            CMP r1,r5
            BEQ Next
            STR r1,[r3],#4
            B Next

EQ74        SUB r2,#1
            LDR r1,[r2],#4
            CMP r1,r4
            BEQ Next
            CMP r1,r5
            BEQ Next
            STR r1,[r3],#4
            B Next
        
Stop        STRB r1,[r3,#1]!
    
            AREA Assign5, DATA, READONLY
            ALIGN
STRING1     DCB "the man t went to the mall"
Eos         DCB 0x00
THEE        DCD 0x74686500
THE         DCD 0x74686520
STRING2     space 0x7F
;he/     DCD 0x686500
;he      DCD 0x686520




    
            END
```

[image: Pic of when the code stops working]

Comment: Sorry about the format of the code, I didn't know it would do that or how to change it

Comment: You are using misaligned accesses, possibly read beyond the end of the string and you skip 4 bytes instead of 1 on a mismatch.